# Must an SV inout port be only in the top module?

Tags: fpga, system-verilog

When an inout port is used for read and write simultaneously it is necessary to use the "?:" operator with the HiZ to assign the port.

```
inout   [7:0]some_port;
wire    [7:0]port_in;
reg     [7:0]port_out;
reg     is_output;
...
assign port_in  = some_port;
assign some_port= is_output ? 8'bz : port_out;
```

Suppose that the design contains several levels of modules and the bottom module has a number of ports. Some of these ports are used by middle level modules. The other ports are directly used as inout of the FPGA.
Must I to drag inout ports through all hierarchy of modules as a separated *port_in / port_out / is_output* and then assign it in the top level module to the inout port? Can I assign somehow an inout port in the bottom module and then forward this port through all levels to the top? If I can't, do the professional SV programmers uses some macros to do this action with minimum strings of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no requirement for `inout` ports to be placed only in the top level. That being said, an FPGAs typically don't support internal tri-state buffers, so the use of them in internal modules is not necessarily representing a bidirectional signal.

In your case where you wish to feed a tristate signal from a lower level module up to the top level, this is perfectly acceptable. Just connect the `inout` signal to the port connection list of your submodule. As long as each `inout` pin connects ultimately to only one tristate buffer design at any level in the hierarchy, a proper tristate buffer will inferred. Remember, wires have no concept of direction until one is specified by an assignment, so feeding a bidirectional wire through the hierarchy is acceptable.

Where things get a bit more interesting is when you connect two `inout` signals *inside* the FPGA. Typical FPGAs don't have internal tristates, so instead the synthesis tool has to infer multiplexing/demultiplexing logic (usually with some form of priority to avoid bus contention). This can cause differences between simulation and synthesis - sim might show `x` for bus contention, but in synthesis one of the signals will take priority due to the multiplexer structure.

An example:

```
// Top level module inout represents a tri-state buffer
module topLevel(
    inout [1:0] tlBidir
);
// inout can be fed entirely into one module, or shared between multiples
subModule first (
    .bidir(tlBidir[0])
);
subModule second (
    .bidir(tlBidir[1])
);
// This one is **not** a tristate buffer as used internally
// It will infer a multiplexer/demultiplexer structure.
wire internalWire;
subModule third (
    .bidir(internalWire)
);
assign internalWire = ctrl ? 1'b0 : 1'bz;

endmodule

// A submodule which describes tristate buffer behaviour.
// Can be at any level
module subModule(
    inout bidir
);

wire ctrl;
wire outVal;
wire inVal;

assign bidir = ctrl ? 1'bz : outVal;
assign inVal = bidir;

...

endmodule
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to define the `ctrl` signal in the module topLevel, or is there some magic behind-the-curtains deduction that it is related to the other ctrl signal? (which would only be possible for 2 module instances writing to the wire)

Comment: @mxt3 you're correct, you would need something like `wire ctrl;` in the topLevel example. It was a quick and dirty example to show how things can be used, so has not been test compiled, nor is it a complete functional module.